# How to tell apart Linux from Windows 10 bash while making bash scripts

Tags: bash, windows-10

I'm making a bash script. My custom bashrc, to be more precise.
And I need to have separate configs, depending on what "Linux" I am in (the Windows 10 Linux subsystem or actual Linux).

How can I tell them apart?

Things I tried:

1. `$OSTYPE` - both return `linux-gnu`
2. `uname -a` - both return similar `Linux COMPUTER_NAME_HERE 3.4.0+ #1
   PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
3. `lsb_release -a` - both return `ubuntu xx.xx`
4. `cat /etc/issue.net` - both return `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`
5. `ld -v` - both return `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24`

The only way I have found to make this work is to set some specific username for the Windows sub-system, and use `$USER`, but that is not an option I'm willing to use. I need this to work out of the box, without custom user names, environment variables, etc..

Comment: Hmm, what's this Linux subsystem for Windows 10? How does one install it? Anyway I think any Windows bash recognizes Windows-style paths that have drive letters in them, so check that `c:/` exists, and `./c:/` does not.

Comment: @n.m. Its something, like linux system under windows.. Not like vagrant or others (where u launch linux as virtual system), but rather, linux commands, translatedto windows (at kernel level). Can't explain more, since i'm just learning about it myself.. Just google "ubuntu for windows" and u'll find it. I must say, i'm quite exited abut this, as i love windows, but its hard to use it as development OS.. (Especially for RubyOnRails)

Comment: Ah so it's like wine in the other direction. Neat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`

You can check for Windows with `grep -qi Microsoft /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease 2> /dev/null`

Comment: I'm not positive this is technically correct since I don't have windows bash, but this would be a much better solution than the accepted one if it is correct because you're checking something that would be non ambiguous. There's probably also a comparable /sys file/content as well, though old linux may not have /sys or have it incomplete, but for the positive match, that wouldn't matter. I tend to prefer going directly into /sys rather than using the /proc if possible.

Comment: This is much better way, since windows bash returns `3.4.0-Microsoft` Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Okey, i found an answer. I can use directory check `/mtn/c/Users`, that will be only in windows linux sub-system, like so:

```
if [ -d "/mnt/c/Users" ]; then
  echo "this is windows 10 bash"
fi
```

So, my end code looks like this, in case someone need this:

```
# get "OS type"
# * linux
# * linux_vagrant
# * windows_bash
# * windows_git
# -------------------------------------------
if [ $OSTYPE=="msys" ]; then
  MY_BASH_OS="windows_git"
elif [[ $OSTYPE=="linux-gnu" || -d "/mnt/c/Users" ]]; then
  MY_BASH_OS="windows_bash"
elif [[ $OSTYPE=="linux-gnu" || $USER=="vagrant" ]]; then
  MY_BASH_OS="linux_vagrant"
elif [ $OSTYPE=="linux-gnu" ]; then
  MY_BASH_OS="linux"
else
  echo "NO OS DETECTED. Exiting my_bash"
  return
fi
```

UPDATE: `laktak` Gave a better solution, that is, checking `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`, which is `3.4.0-Microsoft` for windows bash.

Comment: That's a reasonable heuristic, but somebody could have a Windows disk mounted as `/mnt/c` in an environment which isn't Windows.

Comment: @tripleee Fair point. But this is the best solution i could come up with.. Do You have any better solutions?

Comment: @PragmaticEd You Sir, deserve a cookie.
My knowledge of W10 bash is limited, but may I also suggest to look for installed software or ENV var that are present only in linux and not on W10?

Comment: I'm not up on the specifics of windows bash, the ubuntu real variant that is, but I believe lspci does not function. Correct me if that's wrong. Also, many /sys files will be absent, easy to find which by a few quick checks on a windows bash, but since I don't have windows of that recent vintage, can't do the tests, but I believe lspci should show it. However, lspci also doesn't work on arm so that's not an absolute test either. But /sys will show it somewhere almost for certain. Of course, older linux don't have /sys either...